# Applying simplex algorithm to linear program already in $Ax = b$ form?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-programming, numerical-linear-algebra

When applying the simplex algorithm to a linear program with constraints of the form $Ax \le b$, as a first step, one converts it to a so called slack form $Ax = b$ by introducing slack variables to each constraint.  After that transformation has been applied the slack variables become the initial set of basic variables and the initial non-basic variables are the original variables $x$.

If, on the other hand, the original linear program already has constraints of the form $Ax = b$, one could convert them to constraints of the form $Ax \le b$ by simply joining $Ax \le b$ with $-A \le -b$, which doubles the number of constraints.  Then when applying the simplex algorithm you could return to $Ax = b$ constraints (with twice as many slack variables and constraints).

My question is, is there a way to apply the simplex algorithm directly to a linear program of the form $Ax = b$, without taking that indirect route via $Ax \le b$ and $-A \le -b$?  If so, how do you initially parition the variables into basic and non-basic variables, and get to the initial basic feasible solution?

Comment: Are you aware of artificial variables?

Comment: @callculus: What do you mean?

Comment: For instance, the constraint $x_1+2x_2=3$ can be written as $x_1+2x_2+a_1=3$. So the initial solution is $(x_1,x_2,a_1)=(0,0,3)$. For every $=$- and $\geq-$constraint you introduce an artifical variable $a_i$

Comment: @callculus: I don't understand sorry.  If a constraint is $x_1 + 2x_2 = 3$ then $x_1 + 2x_2 + a_1 = 3 \implies a_1 = 0$, so $(0,0,3)$ is not a valid solution, and what's the point of adding $a_1$?  Are you sure you know how the simplex algorithm works?  It is necessary knowledge to answer this question I think.

Comment: *"Are you sure you know how the simplex algorithm works? "* **Yes**. Have you googled the  tern "artificial valriable"?

Comment: @callculus: Ok, I've looked up artificial variable.  I'm not sure I see how it answers my question though.

Comment: "*My question is, is there a way to apply the simplex algorithm directly to a linear program of the form $Ax = b$, without taking that indirect route via $Ax \le b$ and $-A \le -b$?*" You introduce artificial variables.

Comment: And now, Andrew?

Comment: @callculus: I can't quite figure out why artificial variables are necessary.  Why can't I just perform row reductions on the tableau to create an identity submatrix and form basic variables out of the original ones, or won't that work?  If not, why not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach prescribed for original equality constraints in the linear program in CLRS (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms) Chapter 29 is indeed to introduce opposing inequality constraints (ie $\vec\alpha_i \cdot \vec x = b_i$ becomes the two opposing constraints $\vec\alpha_i \cdot \vec x \le b_i$ and $-\vec\alpha_i \cdot \vec x \le -b_i$)

The alternative approach of artificial variables (not mentioned in CLRS) is essentially to augment a new variable $k_i \ge 0$ on each equality constraint $\vec\alpha_i \cdot \vec x = b$ changing it to an inequality constraint $\vec\alpha_i \cdot \vec x +k_i \le b$, then make a first pass of the simplex algorithm to maximize $\sum - k_i$.  If the resulting solution has all $k_i = 0$ (nonbasic) then they can be eliminated from the linear program, and the resulting solution is then the initial solution for a second pass (without the artificial variables) of the simplex algorithm maximizing the original cost function $\sum c_i x_i$.  Otherwise, if the first pass fails (a $k_i > 0$) then the linear program is infeasible.

I was actually searching for a third alternative that is simpler and more computationally efficient than either of the above, but I have failed to find any.  Given no such solution is mentioned in CLRS I assume it either doesn't exist or is not known.